# Which license is final for google's android play-services? ASL2.0 or Android SDK?

Tags: apache-2.0, license, android

My android application has some com.google.android.gms.play-services-* libraries as dependencies.   Let's take play-services-ads-19.7.0 as an example.

[Google's maven page](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=play-services#com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0) states, that license of that library is [Android Software Development Kit License](https://developer.android.com/studio/terms.html), but in downloaded aar file in AndroidManifest.xml there is Apache 2.0 notice

At the end of the day, which is final? Is it any or both of these licenses?

Or is it Android SDK License for play-services-* and ASL2.0 for some third party libraries?

Comment: IMO, the most likely case is that the Apache license was included due to third-party libraries. But I haven't checked, so not an answer.